# Changing colour mode of black in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb

I was under the impression that, to convert the colour mode of an InDesign document, you just had to modify `Edit > Transparency Blend Space` and change the colour mode of all swatches.

But I've recently realised that the default `Black` swatch will stay as it was when the document was created... and of course, you can't modify it in the way that you can with other swatches.

I suppose you could create a new 'black' swatch and set all blacks to that. But it would be a little tricky to select all of the default blacks to change them (maybe you would miss some).

Is there a more feasible solution to this without having to create a new document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

First, save your file as IDML.
Knowing that an IDML file is basically an archive of XML files, you can open it as an archive (using a (de)compression tool).  Do not decompress it, just open the archive.
Open the Resources folder, then the Preferences.XML file.
In a text editor, look for

```
 Intent="PrintIntent"
```

and change to

```
Intent="WebIntent"
```

or obviously, the other way round depending whether you want to change [Black] to RGB or CMYK.

Save in archive and reopen the IDML file in Indesign.
Hope that helps

Edit: Oh, and by the way, if you have tons of swatches, you may want to run a single line script to change them all to RBG or CMYK (or Lab, why not...)

```
app.activeDocument.colors.everyItem().properties = {space:ColorSpace.CMYK};
```

or

```
app.activeDocument.colors.everyItem().properties = {space:ColorSpace.RGB};
```